# FQL link_stat Values Not Correct

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

I am trying to access the like_stat information for a FB Page, specifically `facebook.com/womenmakemovies`. Navigating to the page manually, the Likes tile shows over 14K likes for the page.

In order to access this data using the FB API, I ran the following query:
`SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count, commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="facebook.com/womenmakemovies"`

All of the "counts" that were selected returned with the value of 0.

Is there some other way to gather all of this data in a single query or some alteration I can make to the current query in order to get the proper data?

Side Note: I am having this issue with other pages also, but most pages I am getting stats for are returning with the correct data given the above query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't query a Facebook page with `link_stat`. You have to use either the [page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/) or [insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/) tables.

This will get you the current number of likes your page has:

```
 SELECT name, fan_count, new_like_count FROM page WHERE username="womenmakemovies"
```

Answer (score 2):

For the likes count you could just use: `https://graph.facebook.com/womenmakemovies`

```
{
   "name": "Women Make Movies",
   "is_published": true,
   "website": "www.wmm.com\nwww.youtube.com/wmmnyc",
   "username": "womenmakemovies",
   "founded": "1972",
   "company_overview": "Women Make Movies is the world's leading distributor of independent films by and about women, with a focus on cutting-edge documentaries that give depth to today's headlines, as well as artistically and intellectually challenging works in all genres. Our films are showcased in prestigious exhibition venues and festivals both nationally and internationally. The Women Make Movies collection of more than 500 films and videotapes is also used by thousands of educational, community and cultural organizations annually.\n\n\n\n",
   "mission": "http://www.wmm.com/about/general_info.shtml",
   "products": "DISTRIBUTION SERVICE\nhttp://www.wmm.com/filmcatalog/new_releases.shtml \n\nPRODUCTION ASSISTANCE PROGRAM\nhttp://www.wmm.com/filmmakers/production_assistance.shtml\n \n\n",
   "about": "www.wmm.com youtube.com/wmmnyc twitter.com/womenmakemovies",
   "location": {
      "street": "462 broadway, ste 500",
      "city": "New York",
      "state": "NY",
      "country": "United States",
      "zip": "10013",
      "latitude": 40.72103,
      "longitude": -74.00049
   },
   "general_info": "WMM Funders:\n\nNew York State Council on the Arts\nNational Endowment for the Arts\nNew York City Department of Cultural Affairs\nThe Educational Foundation of America\nThe Little Family Foundation\nThe Weinstein Company\nThe Friends of Women Make Movies",
   "checkins": 6,
   "were_here_count": 33,
   "talking_about_count": 142,
   "category": "Non-profit organization",
   "id": "6574279597",
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/womenmakemovies",
   "likes": 14704,
   "cover": {
      "cover_id": "10150730604649598",
      "source": "http://sphotos-f.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/s720x720/536830_10150730604649598_87318500_n.jpg",
      "offset_y": 74
   }
}
```